# SQL Server - Multiplying row values for a given column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have data in my SQL Server like this:

```
ID     Number    
----------------     
   1       1
   1       2
   1       3
   2       2 
   2       2
   1       0
```

Then for each ID, I need to multiply all the values of number. In this case for `ID = 1`, I need `1*2*3*0` which is 0

How do I do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: And someone deleted their comment, but this looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912204/why-is-there-no-product-aggregate-function-in-sql

Comment: **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415143)** based on duplicated answer