# Calculate running product with custom expression in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables, first table `section` with schema as:

```
SecID  |      Date     |   SecReturn
-------|---------------|--------------
  208  |   2015-04-01  |   0.00355
  208  |   2015-04-02  |   -0.00578
  208  |   2015-04-03  |   0.00788
  208  |   2015-04-04  |   0.08662
  105  |   2015-04-01  |   0.00786
```

and the second table `SectionDates` with schema as:

```
SecID |  MonthlyDate  |  DailyDate
------|---------------|-------------
208   |   2015-04-02  |  2015-04-03
105   |   2015-04-01  |  2015-04-01
```

I want to calculate the running product on `SecReturn` column of the table `Section` with date range (*DailyDate* to *MonthlyDate*) from second table `SectionDates`.

Running product will be calculated for each *sectionID* based on formula :

```
Date       |   SecReturn   |  SectionTotal
-----------|---------------|--------------------
2015-04-01 |  X (lets say) | (1+x)-1
2015-04-01 |  Y            | (1+x)(1+y)-1
2015-04-01 |  Z            | (1+x)(1+y)(1+z)-1
```

After applying above calculation values will be computed in `SectionTotal` column as for date *2015-04-01* computed value will be *(1+0.00355)-1*. Similarly, for date *2015-04-02* computed value will be *(1+0.00355)(1+-0.00578)-1* and for date *2015-04-03* computed value will be *(1+0.00355)(1+-0.00578)(1+0.00788)-1* and so on.

The final output:

```
 SecID |  Date      |   SectionTotal 
-------|------------|-----------------  
  105  | 2015-04-01 |  0.00786          
  208  | 2015-04-01 |  0.00355          
  208  | 2015-04-02 |  -0.0022505       
  208  | 2015-04-03 |  0.0056117
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please show us what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
SELECT SecID, [Date], [SecReturn], 
       ROUND((1 + SecReturn) * COALESCE(v,1) - 1, 5) AS SectionTotal   
FROM mytable AS t1
OUTER APPLY (  
    SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(SecReturn + 1))) AS v
    FROM mytable AS t2
    WHERE t1.SecID = t2.SecID AND t1.[Date] > t2.[Date]) AS t3
```

`OUTER APPLY`, which is available in SQL Server 2005 AFAIK, fetches all records to be considered in running multiplication calculation.

Using the formula for a multiplication aggregate, found in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912204/why-is-there-no-product-aggregate-function-in-sql) you can obtain desired result.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8415/2)

Comment: It should be COALESCE(v,1) and I would consider adding ROUND() to account for the loss of precision that's going to result from the EXP function. EDIT: actually it could be done in the same way without the outer apply in this way - `ROUND((SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(1+[SecReturn]))) FROM mytable WHERE [SecID] = t1.[SecID] AND [Date] <= t1.[Date]) - 1, 5)`

Comment: You should note that this O(n²) and inefficient for large tables. In the absense of windowing constructs in later versions of SQL Server, sometimes a `CURSOR` can be more efficient (depending on the size of the input).