# How to compute cumulative product in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below table with 2 columns, DATE & FACTOR. I would like to compute cumulative product, something like CUMFACTOR in SQL Server 2008.

Can someone please suggest me some alternative.[image]

Comment: Do you have the ROW column in your data?

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3912204/521799)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's not `PROD()` aggregate or window function in SQL Server (or in most other SQL databases). But you can emulate it as such:

```
SELECT Date, Factor, exp(sum(log(Factor)) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) CumFactor
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Hello Lukas, thanks for your quick response. Currently I'm in SQL Server 2008, unfortunately LEAD and LAG functions are not available in this version. So any other alternatives ?

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Neither solution matches the values in the OP's CumFactor column.

Comment: @knot22: Meh, thanks for the hint. The question was edited 2 days after my answer was accepted :( Will fix my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by:

```
SELECT A.ROW
    , A.DATE
    , A.RATE
    , A.RATE * B.RATE AS [CUM RATE]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE) as ROW, DATE, RATE
    FROM TABLE
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE) as ROW, DATE, RATE
    FROM TABLE
) B
ON A.ROW + 1 = B.ROW
```

Comment: `LEAD/LAG` were introduced in 2012 version while ranking functions in 2005.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the cumulative product, as displayed in the **CumFactor** column in the original post, the following code does the job:

```
--first, load the sample data to a temp table
select *
into #t
from 
(
  values
  ('2/3/2000', 10),
  ('2/4/2000', 20),
  ('2/5/2000', 30),
  ('2/6/2000', 40)
) d ([Date], [Rate]);

--next, calculate cumulative product
select *, CumFactor = cast(exp(sum(log([Rate])) over (order by [Date])) as int) from #t;
```

Here is the result:
[image]