# Multiplying values of same PKs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
+-----+------+
| qwe | asdd |
+-----+------+
| a   | 3    |
| a   | 4    |
| b   | 5    |
| b   | 6    |
+-----+------+
```

The result should be something like this:

```
+-----+------+
| qwe | asdd |
+-----+------+
| a   | 12   |
| b   | 30   |
+-----+------+
```

I wrote a code that may be only applied to the actual table, but if we add a row or more, it is not working well:

```
select qwe, (SUM(asd) - MIN(asd)) * MIN(asd) a from t
group by qwe
```

How would you recommend me to modify this code to make it work properly with tables like this?

```
+-----+------+
| qwe | asdd |
+-----+------+
| a   | 3    |
| b   | 4    |
| b   | 5    |
| a   | 6    |
| a   | 7    |
+-----+------+
```

And get table like this:

```
+-----+------+
| qwe | asdd |
+-----+------+
| a   | 12   |
| b   | 126  |
+-----+------+
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912204/why-is-there-no-product-aggregate-function-in-sql) and its answers may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in `PRODUCT()` function.  Alas.

Assuming all your values are positive, you can do:

```
select qwe, exp(sum(log(asdd))) as aggregate_product
from t
group by qwe;
```

Note:  This can be extended to handle 0 and negative values.  That just adds a lot of extra stuff to the expression, which hides the fundamental logic.

To prevent problems with zero:

```
select qwe, coalesce(exp(sum(log(nullif(asdd, 0)))), 0) as aggregate_product
```

Negative numbers are a bit trickier.

Comment: thanks! i realize that i have to use ifnull somehow, but still can't get into it

Comment: thats how we handle 0 and negatives!
select qwe, nullif(exp(sum(log(asd))),0) as total
from t
group by qwe;