# multiply rows in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following table

```
 ID     Number    
----------------     
   1       41.5
   2       42.5
   3       43.5
   2       44.5   
   2       45.5
   1       46.5
   1       47.5
```

I need to write a query which will return distinct ID's and corresponding Number column values multiplied. For the given table result should be like this

```
ID       Result 
-----------------
  1         41.5 * 46.5 * 47.5
  2         42.5 * 44.5 * 45.5
  3         etc...
```

(without use cursors)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, EXP(SUM(LOG(Number))) as Result
FROM Scores 
GROUP BY id
```

This will work for positive numbers, to multiply negative numbers as well you can use [ABS()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) function to use absolute (positive) value but final result will be positive rather than negative number:

```
SELECT Id, EXP(SUM(LOG(ABS(Number)))) as Result
FROM Scores 
GROUP BY id
```

---

**EDIT: Added test script**

```
DECLARE @data TABLE(id int, number float)

INSERT INTO @data VALUES
(1, 2.2),
(1, 10),
(2, -5.5),
(2, 10)

SELECT Id, EXP(SUM(LOG(ABS(Number)))) as Result 
FROM @data GROUP BY id
```

Output:

```
1   22
2   55
```

Comment: I saw that too, but I'm a bit dubious about involving complicated calculations like `EXP` and `LOG` in what should be simple arithmetic.  Also doesn't work for negative numbers, but the first comment here has a workaround: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/11/13/simple-multiply-function.aspx

Comment: EXP is not aggregate function

Comment: @mellamokb : this would be interesting to compare execution plans

Comment: @Nario : I've added the test script so you can try out it to see whether EXP woudl work with GROUP BY

Comment: @Nario EXP is not an aggregate function, but here it is called after sum which is.  So in the end it is only operating on one number per row and it works quite well that way.  One way to think of it is that the Sum wraps the aggregated column before handing it off to Exp.

Comment: have to think about zero and negative values  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653586/sql-server-query-to-bring-groupwise-multiplication

Comment: @gbn : negative numbers case is covered by `ABS()`, something I missed?

Comment: @gbn: right, I've noted this point in answer `but final result would be positive rather than negative numbe`. It would be great to add solution which persist sign

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, power(sum(log10(num)),10) group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation on row concatenation and Jeff Moden has an excellent article on that at SQL Server Central titled [Performance Tuning: Concatenation Functions and Some Tuning Myths](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/61572/)

---

Edit: @mellamokb It is analogous to concatenation, but requires some modification.  A sample script would be

```
create table testMult (id int, num int)

GO

insert into testMult values (1, 2)
insert into testMult values (1, 3)
insert into testMult values (1, 4)
insert into testMult values (2, 2)

GO

create function dbo.fnMult (@someId int)
returns int as 
begin
    declare @return int
    set @return = 1

    select @return = @return * num
    from testMult
    where id = @someId

    return @return
end

GO

select * 
from testMult

select t1.id,
    dbo.fnMult(t1.id) 
from testMult t1
group by t1.id
```

Which is just a very small variation on the script provided by Jeff Moden in his article.

Comment: You misread his question the same way I did the first time :)  It's multiplication, not concatenation.