# Multiply 2 rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to create a SQL query were I multiply the values of 1 row by the values in its column in the row beneath it. How can I do it? multiplying two columns is easy but i seem stuck on multiplying 2 rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Query to bring groupwise multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653586/sql-server-query-to-bring-groupwise-multiplication)

Comment: Show us your table defs please

Comment: this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185873/multiply-rows-in-t-sql

Comment: There is no such concept as "row beneath it" in any SQL dialect. SQL has no "order"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on your situation.

To simplyfy it... if your table looks like this...

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `number` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

... and some data in it like this...

```
number
------
     2
     3
     4
```

...you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT number 
  FROM test 
  WHERE number = 2) * 
  (SELECT number 
  FROM test 
  WHERE number = 3) AS "product" 
FROM test 
LIMIT 1;
```

You might aswell just `JOIN` the table onto itself.

Answer (score 2):

join on same table

```
select t1.val*t2.val from tab t1, tab t2 where t1.id=5 and t2.id=6
```

or

```
select t1.val*t2.val from tab t1, tab t2 where t1.id=5 and t2.id=t1.id+1
```