# How to create multiple rows combinations based on one COLUMN

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL Table with the following data

Creating table:

```
create TABLE TEMP_RIGHT_ROLLUP_GROUP (
ASSETCODE VARCHAR(20),
RIGHTNAME VARCHAR(50),
ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE TIMESTAMP,
ACQUISITIONENDDATE TIMESTAMP
);
```

Data Ingestion:

```
insert into TEMP_RIGHT_ROLLUP_GROUP VALUES 
('10','R1','2023-01-01 00:00:00.000','2023-10-31 00:00:00.000'),
('10','R1','2024-04-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
('10','R2','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2027-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
('10','R3','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2024-07-31 00:00:00.000'),
('10','R3','2024-10-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000');
```

The data looks like this below:
[image]

Need to create output by multiplying RightName with others RightName

Tried below code:

```
with cte_multiple_window as (
    select
      A.*,
      count(*) over (partition by assetcode,rightname) cnt
    from TEMP_RIGHT_ROLLUP_GROUP A
),
cte_denorm as (
    select
      A.assetcode assetcode_mw,
      A.rightname rightname_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE ACQUISITIONENDDATE_mw,
      B.assetcode assetcode_2,
      B.rightname rightname_2,
      B.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_2,
      B.ACQUISITIONENDDATE ACQUISITIONENDDATE_2
    from cte_multiple_window A
    inner join cte_multiple_window B on A.assetcode = B.assetcode and A.RIGHTNAME <> B.rightname
    where A.cnt > 1 
      and B.cnt = 1
    order by
      A.assetcode,
      A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE,
      A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE
)
-- select * from cte_denorm;
,
cte_norm as (
    select distinct
      A.assetcode_mw,
      A.rightname_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE_mw,
      B.*
    from cte_denorm A
    inner join cte_multiple_window B on (
      (A.assetcode_mw = B.assetcode and
       A.rightname_mw = B.RIGHTNAME and
       A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_mw = B.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE and
       A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE_mw=B.ACQUISITIONENDDATE
      ) or
      (A.assetcode_2 = B.assetcode and
       A.rightname_2 = B.RIGHTNAME and
       A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_2 = B.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE and
       A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE_2 = B.ACQUISITIONENDDATE
      ))
    order by
      A.assetcode_mw,
      A.rightname_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE_mw,
      A.ACQUISITIONENDDATE_mw
)
select *
from cte_norm;
```

Tried different ways like cross join, self join, CTE and row_number nothing is working, can you guys help me to generate this output?

The question is simple. Let's say we have the following data:

`R1   R1   R2   R3   R3`

If there are any repeated rights, then we need to create all possible combinations like the below:

```
R1_1   R2   R3_1

R1_1   R2   R3_2

R1_2   R2   R3_1

R1_2   R2   R3_2
```

Expected SQL output:

[image]

Comment: Is the number of groups R1-R4 fixed?

Comment: This isn't even valid code: you can't have an `ORDER BY` in a CTE without a `TOP`, and there is no reason why you would ever want one. It's unclear what exactly the logic is, even after reading your code. `DISTINCT` is another strange artifact: what is it trying to achieve?

Comment: No, R1-R4 not fixed.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, Let's forget about my code. Let's forget about my code. will explain the requirement here.
we have the following data:
R1   R1   R2   R3   R3
If there are any repeated rights, then we need to create all possible combinations like the below:
{R1_1   R2   R3_1}

{R1_1   R2   R3_2}

{R1_2   R2   R3_1}

{R1_2   R2   R3_2}

Comment: @harsha where did I say I downvoted the question, and how did I make the question "less visible"? If it's a complex problem, then **readable** code is paramount, so that at least the code can be easily understood, even if the task it competes is difficult.

Comment: I just noticed, your columns are defined as a `timestamp` (a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`); you can't have 2 `timestamp` columns in a table, and it can't store a date and time value (it's a `binary(8)`). None of your code or data is valid here.

Comment: It's a Snowflake create statement, and those who know SQL will understand what is timestamp is and how to convert it into their native programming language.

Comment: For your information, Snowflake will allow two or more timestamps in a table.
And I used examples and images to clearly explain my requirements.

Comment: OK so you are using Snowflake, not SQL Server, that explains the syntax errors. Tagging your question correctly would have helped a lot of people.

Comment: Most SQL Server and Snowflake syntax are the same, and this question is more about the logic if we are able to solve it in one place it is easy to convert into another.
There are more people with SQL Server skill sets than Snowflake so I tagged SQL Server.

Comment: Is this question still active? I have a start on an answer, but don't want to waste my time working on it if you've already moved on and won't evaluate it ...

Comment: @RobertSheahan it is still active, I'm looking for a solution, It'd be great if you're able to offer a solution. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you asked for an answer without loops (Cursors, I assume), and while the cursor based solution was pretty efficient (a single forward only pass through) and relatively easy to understand, a set based solution is possible so I'll present it here. If you get a chance to compare them I'm curious how different the performance is, but regardless here is your set based answer. Note that it uses no cursors, no temp tables, and no recursive CTEs, so it should be very fast.

EDIT: The original version produced too small a tally table. Normally in pure SQL I'd use ROW_NUMBER on a big system table or view like `sys.objects`, or maybe specially build one (many articles on the internet about building tally tables) but I'm unfamiliar with Snowflake and wasn't sure if you'd have access to system objects, so I built a bigger one by cross joining `cteExp` (the expanded names of all `RightName` instances). I haven't worked out why my original math was wrong or under what conditions this might possibly still be too small (I doubt it though, this will draw from a list bigger than the number of distinct RNs squared) but here is a corrected version. I don't have time to debug this further today, though perhaps this weekend I'll revisit and try to provide commentary.

```
WITH cteSample as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (CONVERT(nvarchar(20), '10'),CONVERT(nvarchar(50),'R1')
            ,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')
            ,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-10-31 00:00:00.000')),
        ('10','R1','2024-04-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R1','2022-04-01 00:00:00.000','2025-12-31 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R1','2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2025-01-31 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R1','2020-06-01 00:00:00.000','2024-05-01 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R1','2020-02-01 00:00:00.000','2021-02-28 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R1','2023-01-01 00:00:00.000','2024-12-31 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R2','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2027-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R2','2020-01-01 00:00:00.000','2022-12-31 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R2','2021-01-01 00:00:00.000','2022-12-31 00:00:00.000'),--Used for edge testing
        ('10','R3','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2024-07-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R3','2024-10-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        --('10','R3','2024-12-01 00:00:00.000','2025-12-01 00:00:00.000'), --Used for edge testing
        ('10','R4','2022-01-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000')
        --, ('10','R4','2023-01-01 00:00:00.000','2025-12-31 00:00:00.000')--Used for edge testing
        ) as SampleTable(ASSETCODE, RIGHTNAME, ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE, ACQUISITIONENDDATE)
), cteIDs as (
    SELECT *
        , RIGHTNAME as RNBase
        --We can use IDOverAll if JOIN on RIGHTNAME is a bottleneck, any ID will work
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RIGHTNAME, ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE) -1 as IDOverAll
        --For IDInGroup it MUST be consecutive whole numbers!
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHTNAME ORDER BY ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE) -1 as IDInGroup
    FROM cteSample as S
), cteBaseRNs as (
    SELECT RNBase, COUNT(*) as GroupSize
        --For IDOfGroup we can use any ID
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RNBase) as IDOfGroup
    FROM cteIDs as S
    GROUP BY RNBase
),cteWeighted as (
    SELECT *
        --exp(sum(log(column))) effectively makes product 
        --see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653586/sql-server-query-groupwise-multiplication
        , sum(log(GroupSize)) OVER (ORDER BY IDOfGroup ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as PreWeightLog
        , sum(log(GroupSize)) OVER (ORDER BY IDOfGroup DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as PostWeightLog
        , log(GroupSize) as ThisWeightLog
    FROM cteBaseRNs
), cteExp as (--Expanded RightNames to include _#
    SELECT I.*, S.GroupSize, S.IDOfGroup
        --If there is only 1 RN acquisition range, leave it bare
        , CASE WHEN S.GroupSize = 1 THEN I.RNBase 
            ELSE CONCAT (I.RNBase, '_', CONVERT(nvarchar(5), IDInGroup))
            END as RNExt --But if more then 1 append _0, _1, ...
    FROM cteBaseRNs as S INNER JOIN cteIDs as I on I.RNBase = S.RNBase 
), cteGroups as (
    SELECT W.RNBase, W.GroupSize, W.IDOfGroup
        , EXP(PreWeightLog - ThisWeightLog) as PreWeight --How many combinations before
        --How many combinations in total
        , EXP(PreWeightLog + PostWeightLog - ThisWeightLog) as TotalWeight 
    FROM cteWeighted as W
),ctePreTally as ( --We need a set of consecutive whole numbers the same size as the output
    --In pure SQL I'd use a view like sys.objects to generate it, but I don't know what's 
    --available in snowflake, so I'll overbuild from CROSS JOINS on tables we have
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY E.IDOverAll) - 1 as Tally 
        , G.TotalWeight as NumberOfCombos
        , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cteGroups) as NumberOfGroups
    FROM cteExp as E CROSS JOIN cteExp as E2 CROSS JOIN cteGroups as G
),cteTally as ( --We need a set of consecutive whole numbers the same size as the output
    SELECT Tally, NumberOfCombos, NumberOfGroups
    FROM ctePreTally
    WHERE Tally < NumberOfCombos * NumberOfGroups
), ctePreOut as ( --Build the output list with each distinct RN for each of the number of combinations
    SELECT G.*, T.Tally + 1 as OutGroup --For user display
        , CONVERT(bigint,FLOOR(T.Tally/PreWeight)) % GroupSize as IDInGroup
    FROM cteTally as T CROSS JOIN cteGroups as G
    WHERE T.Tally < NumberOfCombos 
) SELECT --O.*, '---', G.* --Now build the final output and put it in the right order, 
    --adding back in the details we didn't carry like Acqutsition dates
    G.AssetCode, G.RightName, G.RNExt, G.ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE, G.ACQUISITIONENDDATE, O.OutGroup
FROM ctePreOut as O 
    INNER JOIN cteExp as G 
        on O.RNBase = G.RNBase AND O.IDInGroup = G.IDInGroup 
ORDER BY O.OutGroup, O.IDOfGroup
```

This produces the following output

| AssetCode | RightName | RNExt | ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE | ACQUISITIONENDDATE | OutGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | R1 | R1_0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_0 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2024-07-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_1 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_0 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2024-07-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_0 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_1 | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_1 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_1 | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |

Comment: Hi @Robert Sheahan, I'm getting the expected output, thanks once again!! you're awesome.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Snowflake and getting results very fast

Comment: If the number of groups increased then this logic is not working.
For example, if I took R1 - 7, R2 - 3, R3 - 2, R4 - 1 occurrence then the following logic should return 7*3*2*1 = 42 groups and 42*4 = 168 records but it returning only 13 groups and 52 records

Comment: @harsha, I'll take a look and get back to you

Comment: @harsha, I have posted a correction. The tally table didn't scale fast enough with increasing data and now scales with the square of the count of RightNames. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: thanks for the quick turnaround; the above code works!

Comment: Can I get you're IDs like LinkedIn/Gmail/Instagram/Facebook/Whatsapp?

Comment: @harsha, I'm not on Facebook or the like, but I think you can search for me on LinkedIn, mention your StackOverflow username so I know it's you. I don't check it often (I'm not a big social media fan) but I'll make a point of checking this week to look for you.

Comment: I'm seeing multiple profiles with your name not sure which one is yours, I'm adding my profile link here
https://www.linkedin.com/in/sri-harsha-koneru-12a1b19b
Can you please send request or msg

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's not as efficient as it might be and definitely could use some cleanup, but it works. I might come back and post a second solution using set based logic instead of a cursor, but the cursor based solution works and is (relative to a set based solution) easy to understand.

The basic principle is to find a set of "RightName" values and find how many alternatives there are for each. Once you have that, build an output set that has that many copies of the list of names, and then iterate over that set to "count up" (use successively higher alternatives to the first of each RightName) as you increase the "Output Group" you're working with.

Anyway, here is the code, and sample output is below that, good luck and report back on how it goes!

```
SELECT OutIDLog, CONVERT(nvarchar(4000), LogValue) as LogValue 
INTO #Log FROM (VALUES (0, 'Log table')) as LogTbl(OutIDLog, LogValue);

WITH cteSample as (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
        (CONVERT(nvarchar(20), '10'),CONVERT(nvarchar(50),'R1')
            ,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-01-01 00:00:00.000')
            ,CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2023-10-31 00:00:00.000')),
        ('10','R1','2024-04-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R2','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2027-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R3','2023-02-01 00:00:00.000','2024-07-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R3','2024-10-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000'),
        ('10','R4','2022-01-01 00:00:00.000','2026-12-31 00:00:00.000')
        ) as SampleTable(ASSETCODE, RIGHTNAME, ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE, ACQUISITIONENDDATE)
), cteIDs as (
    SELECT *
        , RIGHTNAME as RNBase
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RIGHTNAME, ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE) -1 as IDOverAll
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHTNAME ORDER BY ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE) -1 as IDInGroup
    FROM cteSample as S
) SELECT * 
INTO #DataWithIDs
FROM cteIDs;

WITH cteBaseRNs as (
    SELECT RNBase, COUNT(*) as GroupSize
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RNBase) as IDOfGroup
    FROM #DataWithIDs as S
    GROUP BY RNBase
), cteExp as (
    SELECT I.*, S.GroupSize, S.IDOfGroup
        , CONCAT (I.RNBase, '_', CONVERT(nvarchar(5), IDInGroup)) as RNExt
    FROM cteBaseRNs as S INNER JOIN #DataWithIDs as I on I.RNBase = S.RNBase 
), cteTally as (
    SELECT IDOverAll as Tally FROM cteExp
), cteOutGroups as (
    SELECT row_number() over (ORDER BY T.Tally, IDOfGroup) as OutID
        , R.*, 0 as IDInGroup --Zero based ordinal to distinguish between duplicate base names
        , CASE WHEN IDOfGroup = 1 THEN T.Tally ELSE 0 END as ToAdd
        , 0 as Remainder, T.Tally + 1 as OutGroup
    FROM cteTally as T CROSS JOIN cteBaseRNs as R
    WHERE T.Tally < (SELECT exp(sum(log(GroupSize))) FROM cteBaseRNs)
)SELECT * 
INTO #OutTable
FROM cteOutGroups as O
ORDER BY OutGroup, IDOfGroup

SELECT * FROM #DataWithIDs
SELECT * FROM #OutTable

--
DECLARE --Working variables
    @Carry INT
    , @TempAdd INT
    , @LastID INT
    , @NewID INT
    , @LastOutID INT
    , @TempInt INT;

DECLARE --Cursor variables
    @OutGroup INT,
    @OutID INT, 
    @GroupSize INT,
    @IDInGroup INT,
    @IDOfGroup INT,
    @ToAdd INT,
    @Remainder INT;

DECLARE cursor_Out CURSOR
FOR SELECT OutGroup, OutID, GroupSize, IDInGroup, IDOfGroup, ToAdd, Remainder
    FROM  #OutTable
    WHERE OutGroup > 1 --Leave the first group using the lowest RightName if duplicates
    ORDER BY OutGroup, IDOfGroup;

OPEN cursor_Out;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Out 
INTO @OutGroup, @OutID, @GroupSize, @IDInGroup, @IDOfGroup, @ToAdd, @Remainder;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --NOTE: The cursor starts with the SECOND output group! Leave the first at baseline
        IF @IDOfGroup = 1 BEGIN --
            --For a new block, prepare to count up, but if not a new block keep what it was until used
            SET @TempAdd = 1
        END;
        SET @TempInt = @TempAdd;
        
        IF @GroupSize > 1 BEGIN --If there is only 1 instance of the RightName it can't count up, ignore it
            --Get the last value for this group
            SELECT @LastOutID = OutID, @LastID = IDInGroup
            FROM #OutTable  
            WHERE OutGroup = @OutGroup - 1 AND IDOfGroup = @IDOfGroup

            IF @TempAdd > 0 BEGIN
                --Now we'll increment IDInGroup to cycle through the available copies of RightName
                IF (@LastID + 1) < @GroupSize BEGIN
                    SET @NewID = @LastID + 1;
                    SET @TempAdd = @TempAdd - 1;
                END ELSE BEGIN
                    SET @NewID = 0;
                    --Leave @TempAdd as a carry to also bump up the next
                END; 
            END ELSE BEGIN
                SET @NewID = @LastID 
            END;
            UPDATE #OutTable SET IDInGroup = @NewID WHERE OutID = @OutID;
        END;
        --Debugging
        INSERT INTO #Log (OutIDLog, LogValue) 
        SELECT @OutID, ' @LastID = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @LastID) + ' to ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @NewID) 
            + ' @TempAdd = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @TempInt) + ' to ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @TempAdd) 
            + ' @IDOfGroup = ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @IDOfGroup); 

        --Get the next row (if any) and loop
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_Out 
        INTO @OutGroup, @OutID, @GroupSize, @IDInGroup, @IDOfGroup, @ToAdd, @Remainder;
    END;

CLOSE cursor_Out;

DEALLOCATE cursor_Out;

--If you want to see the inner workings of the cursor, uncomment the following line
--SELECT OutID, RNBase, GroupSize, IDOfGroup, IDInGroup, OutGroup, LogValue FROM #OutTable as O LEFT OUTER JOIN #Log as L ON O.OutID = L.OutIDLog

--Now put it all together!
SELECT D.AssetCode, D.RightName
    ,  CASE WHEN O.GroupSize = 1 THEN D.RightName
        ELSE CONCAT(D.RightName, '_', CONVERT(nvarchar(50), O.IDInGroup +1)) END as RNExtended
    , ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE, ACQUISITIONENDDATE
    , O.OutGroup
FROM #OutTable as O 
    INNER JOIN #DataWithIDs as D on O.RNBase = D.RIGHTNAME 
        AND O.IDInGroup = D.IDInGroup 

DROP TABLE #Log
DROP TABLE #DataWithIDs
DROP TABLE #OutTable
```

Which gives the output

| AssetCode | RightName | RNExtended | ACQUISITIONBEGINDATE | ACQUISITIONENDDATE | OutGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | R1 | R1_1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2024-07-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_2 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2024-07-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 2023-10-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_2 | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 10 | R1 | R1_2 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R2 | R2 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 | 2027-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R3 | R3_2 | 2024-10-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |
| 10 | R4 | R4 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2026-12-31 00:00:00 | 4 |

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. will convert this to a snowflake version, execute it and let you know the results. But is it possible to simplify this code, like eliminating loops?

Comment: @harsha, It might be possible to simplify the code and eliminate the cursor, I was exploring that possibility a bit yesterday, but I do not yet see a way. I figured getting a cursor solution today and exploring a set based solution later was better. Note that the only loop is a single forward only cursor, so it's not as big a performance hit as multiple loops would be. But I'll continue to think about this over the weekend and see what I can come up with. In the meantime, please do report back with performance details, including time, how many distinct RNs you have, how many duplicates, etc.

Comment: Sure, @Robert Sheahan, thanks for your time and efforts, which we really appreciate.

Comment: @harsha, I've been trying to find a non-cursor way to do this and I can't make it work. I might be able to get a recursive CTE to do it, but that would scale worse than a single pass cursor, and would not scale to a large number of RealNames. Have you tried the cursor solution? Does it work and performance is poor or does it not work?

Comment: Hi @Robert Sheahan, I've yet to validate that code. Sorry, I've been on vacation for the last 4 days. will update the status at the end of this week.

Comment: I did not think that I would get an answer to this question. I'm glad you saw this question.

Comment: @harsha, don't implement the Cursor Based Solution yet, I have a set based solution working but I need to clean it up before I post it - hopefully today or tomorrow but maybe not until the weekend when I have more time. It uses no cursors, no loops, no "Recursive CTE calls" and no temporary tables, so it should scale well. I'll post it as a second solution (it's big) as soon as I can get the time to clean it up.

Comment: Perfect! , Looking forward to the solution.